# Sending Array in Ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax, coldfusion

Anybody here understand who understands more Ajax. **I'm not sure how to send a javascript array in an ajax request.** Could someone send me an example of how the ajax request would look? I'm trying to  to grab all the javascript data, bundle it into a container and send it per ajax request to coldfusion but I don't understand much ajax so everything would help me.

**Thank you for all the answers.**

Comment: Any particular reason for the Coldfusion tag on this question?

Comment: @DanBracuk It's because I need to send data from javascript to coldfusion and I try to do it with ajax. Maybe someone who works with coldfusion know how to solve this issue.

Comment: That would be receiving the data once you send it.  This question is about sending it.

Comment: @DanBracuk  For me it's in programming completely new. So that's why i structured the question this way. I'm looking for some answers not for debation why i ask this way.... So thanks for your answer but this is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

**Example using axios library to send array of data in ajax request.**

```
import axios from "axios"
async function sendJavascriptArrayData() {
  const postRequestData = {
    arrayOfStrings: ["react", "svelte", "solidjs"],
    arrayOfNumbers: [1, 2, 3],
  }

  try {
    const res = await axios.post("https://example.com", postRequestData)
    console.log(res.data)

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.response)
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

to send an array javascript through a request you can stringify it ( transform it into plain text) via the JSON.stringify(array) and send it.